# How to create and calculate a formula using an unknown number of variables in C++

Tags: c++

Okay, so this is going to be very complicated to explain through text but I will do my best to try.

I am making a universal calculator where one of the function of the calculator is to process a formula when given an unknown number of variables. I have seen some ways to do this but for how i'm trying to use this calculator, it wont work.
Example for sum of function:

```
while (cin >> input) 
    count++;
```

Normally this would work but the problem is that I can't have the user input the values over and over again for one formula like for this formula: [Formula Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQPB0.png)

(Sorry its easier for me to explain through a picture) In it there are multiple times where I have to use the same numbers over and over again. Here is the entire process if you need it to understand what I'm saying:
[Entire problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiHiI.png)

The problem is that normally I would add another float for every point graph but I don't know ahead of time number of floats the user is going to enter in. The ideal way to do this is for the program to ask the user for all the points on the table and for the user to input those points in a format like: "(1,2) (2,4) (3,6)..."

Thinking ahead, would I make a function where the program creates an integer and assigns the integer to a value on the fly? But then how would the actual math formula interact with the new integers if they haven't been created yet?

Talking about this makes my head hurt....

I actually want to say more:
One idea that I tried to make in my head was something like

```
string VariableName = A [or something]
```

Then you would reassign VariableName = "A" to VariableName = "B" by something like VariableName = "A"+ 1 (which would equal B).

Then you would repeat that step until the user inputs a invalid input. But obviously you can't do math with letters so I wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: C++ supports container classes, that can be used to collect additional elements dynamically. The most prominent class used for that is `std::vector`.

Comment: You need to read a good C++ textbook and make some simpler programs first.

Comment: Research how to write a lexer and a parser (I'd start with a "recursive descent" parser as those are fairly simple). Also google yacc and bison (or boost::spirit if you want to get *really* fancy).

Comment: Search the internet for "shunting yard algorithm c++ precedence".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you for letting me know the algorithm, which I'm ashamed to have never known... I've used Bison and Flex and wrote a toy C compiler, but never knew about that. I believe that's not what the OP needs, but it's good to learn something old!

Comment: @CostantinoGrana: I just recently switched from using a grammar for evaluating a math expression to using the shunting yard algorithm.  IMHO, the shunting yard algorithm is simpler and handles more cases better.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are overthinking this. It's pretty simple and it doesn't need to store the input values.

The main thing to note is that you need to compute (step 2) the sum of the values of X and Y, the sum of their product and the sum of X squared. To compute the sum of a lot of values you don't need all the values together, but just one at the time. Exactly as when a user provides them. So declare four variables: `sx`, `sy`, `sxy`, `sxx`. Initialize them to 0. At every couple of X and Y you get, add it to `sx` and `sy`, add their product to `sxy` and the product of X with itself to `sxx`.

Now you've got all you need to compute the final result for a and b.

Anyway a good C++ book would be useful.